# Group by latest date with conditions

Tags: sql-server, mysql, pivot, greatest-n-per-group

I need your help!

Let's say I have this table:

| Instance | Date | MetricID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marc | 09/14/21 | 1 | 5 |
| Marc | 09/14/21 | 2 | 2 |
| Marc | 09/14/21 | 3 | 1 |
| John | 09/14/21 | 1 | 10 |
| John | 09/14/21 | 2 | 1 |
| John | 09/14/21 | 3 | 1 |
| Marc | 09/15/21 | 1 | 15 |
| Marc | 09/15/21 | 2 | 0 |
| Marc | 09/15/21 | 3 | 1 |
| John | 09/15/21 | 1 | 10 |
| John | 09/15/21 | 2 | 1 |
| John | 09/15/21 | 3 | 0 |

And I want this:

| Instance | LatestDateMetric1 | LatestDateMetric2 | LatestDateMetric3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marc | 09/15/21 | 09/14/21 | 09/15/21 |
| John | 09/15/21 | 09/15/21 | 09/14/21 |

I tried this code, It looks a bit like I want except It takes the value even if it is null and the result is by line not column.

```
 SELECT "Instance", "MetricID", MAX("Date") as "LatestDate"
FROM "API_Metric2"
GROUP BY "Instance", "MetricID"
```

This is the result I got:

| Instance | MetricID | LatestDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marc | 1 | 09/15/21 |
| Marc | 2 | 09/15/21 |
| Marc | 3 | 09/15/21 |
| John | 1 | 09/15/21 |
| John | 2 | 09/15/21 |
| John | 3 | 09/15/21 |

And I also tried this:

```
SELECT "Instance", 
            CASE WHEN "MetricID"=1 AND "Value" NOT NULL THEN MAX("Date") ELSE 0 END) AS "LatestDateMetric1",
            CASE WHEN "MetricID"=2 AND "Value" NOT NULL THEN MAX("Date") ELSE 0 END) AS "LatestDateMetric2",
            CASE WHEN "MetricID"=3 AND "Value" NOT NULL THEN MAX("Date") ELSE 0 END) AS "LatestDateMetric3"
    FROM "StackExemple"
    GROUP BY "Instance", "Date", "MetricID"
```

But I get this error message:

> Parse error at line 2, column 66.  Encountered: "Value"

***Edit***:  I also got this code which seems to be working but It's not taking the null values into account. It only display 09/15/21 as the LatestDate for all metrics.

```
SELECT "InstanceName",
                    MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 4 THEN "Date" END) as "LatestProjectCreated",
                    MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 5 THEN "Date" END) as "LatestActionCreated",
                    MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 8 THEN "Date" END) as "LatestUserCreated"
FROM "API_InstanceMetric"
GROUP BY "InstanceName";
```

***Edit2***:   The issue persists even with adding the "Value IS NOT NULL" as below

```
SELECT "Instance",
                    MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 1  AND "Value" IS NOT NULL THEN "Date" END) as "LatestProjectCreated",
                    MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 2 AND "Value" IS NOT NULL THEN "Date" END) as "LatestActionCreated",
                    MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 3 AND "Value" IS NOT NULL THEN "Date" END) as "LatestUserCreated" FROM "StackExemple" GROUP BY "Instance";
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Do you want SQL Server or MySQL? Please delete as appropriate! Also, please put your table structure and data on dbfiddle.uk. It's `x IS NOT NULL` and not `x NOT NULL` in your SQL! Also, if you can, you should dispense with the quoted identifiers - you don't need them - you have no spaces or special characters (i.e. ^[A-Za-z0-9_]). And you don't want the values?

Comment: @Vérace Thanks for your comment! I'm using Zoho Analytics so both SQL Server and MySQL are fine. I only need to check if the values are positive but I don't need to aggregate or manipulate them

Comment: Almost forgot - please **always** include the version(s) of your server(s). MySQL 8 in particular introduced a **lot** of new functionality - including (critically for you) CHECK constraints - you just put CHECK (value > 0) and you're done as far as checking goes - for earlier versions of MySQL, you have to use triggers!. Don't forget the fiddle - with any SQL you tried!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, It seems I don't have MySQL8 since the Check clause does not appear. I tried the "Value is not null" but it still returns "09/15/21" for all the metrics :(

Comment: Can you show the results for your working query? It might be good for other users - or even yourself in the future - you'd be amazed how often, if you solve a problem once, it crops up again 6 months/1 year... later and you're going "I've seen this, where did I put the solution?" - if it's up here, you'll always be able to find it!

Comment: The tags I added explain two techniques you may need.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from StackOverflow:

```
SELECT "Instance",
       MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 1 THEN "Date" END) as LatestDateMetric1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 2 THEN "Date" END) as LatestDateMetric2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN "MetricID" = 3 THEN "Date" END) as LatestDateMetric3
FROM "API_Metric2"
WHERE "Value" > 0
GROUP BY "Instance";
```

I just needed to add a WHERE clause smh

The result looks exactly like what I expected:

| Instance | LatestDateMetric1 | LatestDateMetric2 | LatestDateMetric3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marc | 09/15/21 | 09/14/21 | 09/15/21 |
| John | 09/15/21 | 09/15/21 | 09/14/21 |